# jquery ui get id of droppable element, when dropped an item

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

How we get the id of droppable element, when dropped an item? Here i use jquery ui and asp.net mvc.

```
 <table id="droppable">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:300px;height:50px">Backlog</td>
    <td style="width:300px;height:50px">Ready</td>
    <td style="width:300px;height:50px">Working</td>
    <td style="width:300px;height:50px">Complete</td>
    <td style="width:300px;height:50px">Archive</td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="cart">
        <td id="BackLog" class="drag"  style="width:120px;height:50px;">

         <img class="draggable" id="1234" src="../../Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png" />

        </td>
            <td id="Ready"  class="drag"  style="width:140px;height:50px">


            </td>
            <td id="Working" class="drag"  style="width:140px;height:50px">

            </td>
            <td id="Complete" class="drag" style="width:140px;height:50px">


            </td>
            <td id="Archive" class="drag" style="width:140px;height:50px">

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
   </table>
```

Here i want to move image in Ist column to other column and get the id of that column.
For drag and drop i use the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: '#imageboundary', axis: "x" });
        $("#droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {                                      
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Project/AddToPhase/' + $(ui.draggable).attr("id") ,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.result').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 100):

To get the id of both the draggable and the droppable elements use the following:

```
$('.selector').droppable({ drop: Drop });

function Drop(event, ui) {
  var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
  var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Sorry might be a little late for you but I have just started using jquery and needed the exact thing.

Comment: this  is wrong. ui.draggable just returns the draggable element not the element that it was dropped on to. use $(this) to get the dropped on to element.

Comment: ui.draggable is undefined for me.

Comment: Thank you, it work perfectly, and I was looking for this answer. 1+

Answer (score 8):

jQuery UI's [droppable API manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) mentions how to get the *"dropped-on-droppable"* very "secretly" in the [section of `greedy` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy):

> `event.target` can be checked to see which droppable received the
>   draggable element

But note that `event.target` contains just a DOM element...

## Answer to your question

You will be able to get the ID in your `droppable`'s `drop` callback through the first parameter `event`.

#### Pure JS

Property: `event.target.id` - *if ID is not set: empty string ""*

Attribute: `event.target.getAttribute('id')` - *if ID is not set: null*

#### jQuery

Property: `$(event.target).prop('id')` - *if ID is not set: empty string ""*

Attribute: `$(event.target).attr('id')` - *if ID is not set: undefined*

### Usage *example*

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".droppablesSelector").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {                                      
          //display the ID in the console log:
          console.log( event.target.id );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

### Additional info

> [**Event**](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event) 
> jQuery's event system **normalizes the event object** according to W3C standards.
> The event object is guaranteed to be
>   passed to the event handler (no checks for window.event required). It
>   **normalizes the target**, relatedTarget, which, metaKey and pageX/Y
>   properties and provides both stopPropagation() and preventDefault()
>   methods.

Answer (score 1):

You hookup a `"drop"` event and interrogate the element that you just dropped. The element being the parameter `"ui"` in the function below

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Have a look at the [documentation.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#propagation)

Comment: Thank you.. We need more explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="listitems">
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code

```
$(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
// sort function callback
function sort_li(a, b){
    return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```