# Get ID of dragged list item in a sortable jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this html:

```
<ul>
    <li id='item1'>First</li>
    <li id='item2'>Second</li>
    <li id='item3'>Third</li>
</ul>
```

and this .sortable jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#listofpages").sortable({

    }
})
```

How can I get the id of the dragged element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562853/jquery-ui-get-id-of-droppable-element-when-dropped-an-item

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inside the [`update`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) event callback you can do this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gefQs/)):

```
$( "#listofpages" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm typing this on my iPhone which doesn't support sortable but this might be a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gefQs/ (jsfiddle isn't that easy on an iPhone) (just tested it and it works! :)

Answer (score 6):

The previous answer was very good however you should use the receive event not update, update fires twice as often as needed and can cause problems because it is firing once for element removed from previous list and fired once for element added to new list.

```
$( "#listofpages" ).sortable({
  receive: function( event, ui ) {
    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
  }
});
```