# Get attributes value of dropped element in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, drag-and-drop

I have 2 meteor templates, each one contains data from another collection.

I'm using the [ui-dropped-event](https://atmospherejs.com/raix/ui-dropped-event) package, which allows me to use the "dropped" event, which is very essential. However, I want to get value of attributes from the dropped element instead the one I dragged the element to. I'm trying to achieve this like this:

This is the dragged object:

```
<li class="dragme">Hey there</li>
```

...which is being dropped to this element:

```
<li class="droptome">test</li>
```

And my JS code goes like this:

```
'dropped .droptome' : function(evt, tmp) {
        console.log($(evt.target).attr("class"));
}
```

This prints the "droptome" class instead of the "dragme" class. I need to reach the dragged element attributes.

Comment: What does console.log($(this).attr("class")); get you?

Comment: Also there is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562853/jquery-ui-get-id-of-droppable-element-when-dropped-an-item

Comment: It gets me "undefined".