# jQuery - Change attribute value after succesfull Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

After a succesfull drag and drop of an DIV (person NT, TVD, LZ or JVR) into an position DIV, I want that that the attribute value called: "data-id" will be updated and stored into the MySQL Database. How can I manage this? I'm stuck.

The database has the following columns: id, name, img, position. I want to write the position (which value is "data-id") to be stored.

Live demo: [planning.dutch-quality.nl](http://planning.dutch-quality.nl)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".boxPersons").each(function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#" + target).append($(this));
  });

  $(".boxPersons").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    containment: '.box',
    cursor: 'move'
  });

  $(".openSpots, .box-persons").droppable({
    accept: ".boxPersons",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var droppable = $(this);
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      // Move draggable into droppable
      draggable.appendTo(droppable);
      draggable.css({
        top: '0px',
        left: '0px'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Likely duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562853/jquery-ui-get-id-of-droppable-element-when-dropped-an-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try of this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dragMe").draggable();
  $("#dropOnMe").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $uiElement = $(ui.draggable), 
          id         = $uiElement.attr("id"),
          dataid     = $uiElement.attr("data-id"),
          dropid     = $(this).attr("data-id");
      console.log(id,dataid,dropid);
      $.post("someUrl",{id:id,dataid:dataid},function() {
        console.log("updated");
      });
      
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html(dataid+" Dropped!");
      $uiElement.attr("data-id",dropid).text("dropped on "+dropid); // set the dataid on the dragged  
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#dragMe {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

#dropOnMe {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="dragMe" data-id="ABCDE"  class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="dropOnMe" class="ui-widget-header" data-id="DEFG">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use this script, it is not updating the value of data-id of the drag me element which should be taken of the drop element. Any idea how I can manage it?

Comment: Have a look at the update. Should be enough to do what you need?

Comment: Thanks @mplugjan!

Answer (score -1):

You can inspect the event object under the drop object.
Like **event.target** will give the div id where you have dragged the box.
Similarly , you can access othjer properties and apply as per your need.

Hope this will help you.